# How to set map extent in Arcgis javascript using spatialReference 4326

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I am using Arcgis Javascript API for my map and the map is coming from Arcgis online usng map by ID.

Here is code

```
         var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(52.37615, 13.11937,52.64877,13.65801,
                  new SpatialReference({wkid:4326}) );

                  var createMapOptions = {
                mapOptions: {
                    extent : startExtent
                },
               };
              arcgisUtils.createMap("c997ee65fad94ce4ae3c3d9618212099","map",createMapOptions).then(function(response){
                 map = response.map;
              }}
             })
```

I want to set map  extent according to Berlin city But it is not working for above extent value and  SpatialReference:4326.

But when I used this extent 
            xmin=1231772.125133422&ymin=6464953.10035588&xmax=1843268.35141480187&ymax=7103966.656819923 with  SpatialReference:102100 ,It wokrs for me.

I don't know why it not working with SpatialReference:4326.

Does Somebody know Why my code is not working for SpatialReference:4326 and its extent.

I want set map extent according 4326 as shown in code.

Comment: `But it is not working for above extent value and SpatialReference:4326.` - what does that mean? What is happening when you execute your code? What does the javascript console show?

Comment: If one of these answers, solves your problem, please check the box under that answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your terms mixed up.

Map extent is the min X, max X, min Y, max Y coordiates. What you're looking to do is change the SRS (spatial reference system); which you cannot do in a web map, as all that I know use a WGS84 Web Mercator, which is the SRS - 102100.

It looks like the two will use different  coordinate values to represent the same area, so you will need to identify where Berlin is within the web mercator format; which will use coordinates similar to -7.09,49.69

Comment: not true.  actually (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) from https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html

Answer (score 2):

The general approach would be:

1. Take coordinates in any spatial reference system
2. Convert those to the SRS used by the web map using a function provided by the Web Mapping API
3. Use the converted coordinates to perform actions on your Web Map.

For step 2 maybe you can look at the code from https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/util_coordinate_converter.html and adapt it to your needs?

Answer (score 2):

The [API page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html) says the extent is set up like this (note the correct order)

new Extent(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, spatialReference).
You have the correct coordinates but you have x and y confused. Try this instead.

```
 var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(13.11937, 52.37615, 13.65801, 52.64877,
                  new SpatialReference({wkid:4326}) );
```

I pasted your coordinates into Google Maps and they work (to represent an extent around Berlin) because Google Maps puts Y before X so (52.37615, 13.11937) is the lower left and (52.64877, 13.65801) is the upper right. You need to put X before Y.

Answer (score 1):

as per the API reference, the coordinate system of your extent and ArcGISTiledMapService layer need to match.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1
"The tiling scheme of an ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer must match the projection of the map."

no problem though.  you can use webMercatorUtils.geographictowebmercator(latLngExtent) if you'd like to convert your extent to web mercator on the fly.